# Primefaces 5: get value not in list from autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

is it possible get a value not in list from autocomplete component?
I must allow to user to choose an element from list or add new element.

My autocmplete is this:

```
        <p:autoComplete  
        id="auto"
        value="#{bean.myobject}"
        completeMethod="#{bean.autoComplete()}"
        var="myvar"
        converter="myConverter"
        itemValue="#{myvar}"
        itemLabel="#{myvar.description}">

        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{bean.handleSelect}">
        </p:ajax>
        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.action}">
        </p:ajax>
    </p:autoComplete>
```

In my bean, handleSelect method works perfectly with object in list.

Action method instead doesn't get value out of list.

Method action is this:

```
    public void action(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {

    //FIRST SOLUTION
    AutoComplete anAutoComplete = (AutoComplete) e.getComponent();
    String aSelection = anAutoComplete.getValue().toString();
    System.out.println(aSelection);

    //SECOND SOLUTION
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIComponent current = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(context);
    Map<String, Object> attrMap = current.getAttributes();
    String test = (String) attrMap.get("auto");
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

Both solution doesn't work (both variable aSelection and test are null).
Where is my mistake?
Thanks.

Comment: you want selected item from autoComplete in your action method?

Comment: No, if user digits a word not in list, I want get that value so I can add after that value in list...

Comment: "if user digits a word not in list"  can you more elaborate

Comment: If my list contains "Cat" and "Dog" and user digits "Bird", I want get value of "Bird" in my bean.... so then I can add "Bird" in list...

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the value of the text digited by the user you have to access the "#{bean.myobject}". There is where you are saving this information. So, in your BackingBean Method action:

```
public void action(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {

...
String aSelection = myObject.toString();
System.out.println(aSelection); ....}
```

A similar example that get each value digited by the user wheter is in the autocompleted list or not.This code is working. In xhtml:

```
<p:autoComplete  
    id="auto"
    value="#{bean.text}"
    completeMethod="#{bean.autoComplete}"
  >
   <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.action}">
   </p:ajax>
</p:autoComplete>
```

In the backing bean named "bean":

```
private String text;

   public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public void action(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {

        String aSelection = text.toString();
        System.out.println(aSelection);

    }

public List<String> autoComplete(String query) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        results.add(query + i);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: If element is not in list, aSelection is null... so application throws NullPointerException.. :-(

Comment: I 've edited the answer to show the code i used. You store the value in the bean attribute each time the user changes it. This value is not null and you can use it

Comment: Your example works because you haven't an object but a String (so I believe). I solved changing converter where I manage value not in list. Thanks anyway.